# Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0xc328bc1a at offset 2503680

Tags: audio, wav, librosa

```
def load_wav_file(file_path):
    try:
        # Load the audio file using librosa
        audio_data, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_path, sr=None)
        return audio_data, sample_rate
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading the audio file: {e}")
        return None, None
    

working_file = pd.read_csv('/home/udita/Audio_File_Details/working_files.csv')

for filename in os.listdir(audio_folder):

    if any(working_file['Filename'] == filename):


        audio_path = os.path.join(audio_folder, filename)
        audio_data, sample_rate = load_wav_file(audio_path)


        if audio_data is not None and sample_rate is not None:
            continue 


        else:
            print(f"Failed to load the audio file {audio_path}")
```

I am trying to load the audio files using librosa and almost all of them have a header error:

Warning: Xing stream size off by more than 1%, fuzzy seeking may be even more fuzzy than by design!
Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0xc328bc1a at offset 2503680.
Note: Trying to resync...
Note: Skipped 932 bytes in input.
Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0xc1f9b81c at offset 4849892.
Note: Trying to resync...
Note: Skipped 932 bytes in input.
Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0xc1e128de at offset 7814344.
Note: Trying to resync...
Note: Skipped 932 bytes in input.
Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0xc0000034 at offset 7890156.
Note: Trying to resync...

I have over 3000 files and I can't seem to get rid of this error.